# video tag full width cutomizable height

Tags: wordpress, video

I am working in wordpress (I don't think it matters much though in this case), and I need to include a header after the menu, full width and only 180px height. But no way it is working!! If I try to put my height (different than 100% or auto), the video becomes small enough to keep the size scaled, but it is not what I need.

The thing is, the final video would be a video recorded through a post box mouth (not sure how it is called), so it is quiet width but not much high.

I'm finding to explain myself quiet hard, so if anyone doesn't understand what I mean, but they have an idea what I can do, please, let me know!!

```
<video id="video" width="100%" height="180px" controls autoplay>'
         . '<source src="'.get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/video/money.mp4" type="video/mp4">'
                 . '<source src="'.get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/video/money.ogg" type="video/ogg">'
                 . '<source src="'.get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/video/money.webm" type="video/webm"></video>
```

I've tried to use plugins but I have the same problem....

I would appreciate any kind of suggestion! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Well, it wasn't very difficult.... maybe it was too early to think properly. So I've just added a wrap and give it the 100% width and 180px height and then overflow:hidden and it solved my issue...

php:

```
if(is_page('solutions')){
         echo '<div class="wrapperVideo"><video id="video" width="100%" height="auto" autoplay loop>'
                 .'<source src="'.get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/video/money.mp4" type="video/mp4">'
                 . '<source src="'.get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/video/money.ogg" type="video/ogg">'
                 . '<source src="'.get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/video/money.webm" type="video/webm">'
                 . '</video>'
                 . '<div class="sentenceOfTheDayVideo"><span>"Enjoy a cup of tea"</span>&nbsp; - SOMEONE</div>'
            . '</div>';
     }
```

css:

```
.wrapperVideo{
     width:100%;
     height:180px;
     overflow:hidden;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Please Use this Plugins

[`https://wordpress.org/plugins/hana-flv-player/`](https://wordpress.org/plugins/hana-flv-player/)

Requird https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/

Usage Example

You can place the specific tag element [hana-flv-player] in your wordpress article to show the video. The 'video' attribute is mandatory. There are other optional attributes. Default values for the options can be defined in this pages. See the bottom of the page for the example.

```
[hana-flv-player 
    video="http://yourwebsite.com/wp-content/plugins/hana-flv-player/babyhana.flv"
    width="1000"
    height="180"
    description="Sarah is having fun in a merry-go-round"
    clickurl="http://yourwebsite.com/"
    clicktarget="_blank"
    player="5"
    autoplay="false"
    loop="false"
    autorewind="true"
    splashimage="http://yourwebsite.com/wp-content/plugins/hana-flv-player/splash.jpg"
    skin="mejs-wmp"
/]
```

Insert flv into template theme files (such as sidebar.php):

Okay, here is the function that you can use in the theme template files to show FLV movie. Basically you need to use hana_flv_player_template_call method. The method takes a single argument. The argument should be just the string of the attributes of usage explained the above. Just copy below code into your theme file and edit red colored attributes accordingly.

```
<?php
if (function_exists('hana_flv_player_template_call')){
    $hana_arg="
video='http://localhost/wp/wp-content/plugins/hana-flv-player/babyhana.flv'
player='2'
width='1000'
height='100'
more_2=\"showStopButton: false, showScrubber: false, showVolumeSlider: false,showMuteVolumeButton: false, 
showFullScreenButton: false, showMenu: false, controlsOverVideo: 'locked',controlBarBackgroundColor: -1,
controlBarGloss: 'none', usePlayOverlay:false \"
";
    echo hana_flv_player_template_call($hana_arg);  
}
?>
```